# Работа с GIT в ветке мастер

Tags: git

Ситуация такая, случайно забыл перейти на новую ветку при разработке новой фичи и остался в мастере. Сделал уже довольно много работы и хотел запушиться,но  не смог так как в этот момент мастер уже далеко ушел вперед.Какие шаги нужно сделать что б сохранить свои данные и сделать успешный мерж ?

Comment: ну чисто в теории мердж можно делать прямо в текущей ветке.

Comment: можно попробовать git cherry-pick в свою ветку, далее в мастере делаете reset hard чтобы он оставался чистым на локали и уже из своей ветки оформляете пулл-реквест или мердж

Comment: @Taarim зачем так сложно-то?

Comment: @PavelMayorov не совсем правильно понял что хочет человек(

Comment: `git pull --rebase origin master`.

Comment: @0andriy похоже что  эта команда  откатит всё до начального состояния  и снесет все мои локальные данные

Comment: @Georgy нет, эта команда ваши данные сохранит. Но всё равно сделает не то что вы просили

Comment: @0andriy так требовалось-то сменить текущую ветку, а у вас текущая ветка так мастером и осталась

Comment: @PavelMayorov, так вы не дочитали пост до конца. Прочтите внимательно. Зачем менять ветку?

Comment: Нет, Эта команда вам сделает всё красиво. И тут же сможете сделать своё слияние. Если вам обязательно нужен merge commit даже для случая fast forward, то для этого тоже есть соответствующие команды.

Comment: @0andriy это вы не дочитали, автору merge нужен, а не rebase, о чём он сообщает открытым текстом.

Comment: @PavelMayorov,  Выстрелить в ногу можно себе по-разному. А к вам вопрос: чем отличается merge fast forward от не такового? По-моему вы плохо понимаете, чего хочет добиться в результате ТС.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если имя ветки - единственное что вас смущает, а с самим мержем проблем нет - то вы всегда можете создать новую ветку в любое время:

```
git checkout -b feature/foo
git branch -f master origin/master
```

Первая команда создаст новую ветку с именем `feature/foo` и переключит вас на неё, вторая команда сбросит ветку master, приведя её в соответствие с origin.

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую :)

Comment: У вас тоже сложно...